# IPN Request.Querystring

Tags: sql, vb.net, paypal, paypal-ipn, request.querystring

Within PayPal i have my notify_url set and it works nicely.

However I want to capture the QueryString such as tx, amt and item_number

I have the following SQL command that I place into the Verify section

SqlCommand("UPDATE ElyPartyInvoices SET TransactionID = '" & Request.QueryString("tx") & "', TotalPaid = " & Request.QueryString("amt") & ", Status = 'Paid' WHERE id = " & Request.QueryString("item_number"), conn)

Have test the code on another enviroment and works fine, so how do i capture tx, amt and item_number within the IPN please?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure ipn is POSTing informations, so your query string would not contain them. But I'm not sure about what is the content of this object in vb.net

Comment: I have literally just worked it out!!

Answer (score 0):

Posts are needed. 
Unfortunately the big companies forget their are beginners and make their samples very difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know vb.net but I am sure PayPal IPN response is same for all the language.

PayPal IPN send response to "notify_url" in post method.

If you want to grab IPN response used below variable:

```
Transactin Id = txn_id,
Amount = mc_gross_1,
Item Number = item_number,
Item Name = item_name
```

If you get all the transaction variable used POST variable to used all the variable.